# Interpretating `allEffects` and missing p-values

Tags: r, logistic, interpretation, glmm, data-visualization

I need to run a logistic regression with random effects, about wheelchair users and hinderance due to environmental barriers:

```
glmer(ts1_ev_access~ts1_age_grouped+ts1_sex+wheelchair_user+stadt_land_code+
                    ts1_language+(1|MEDSTAT04_dissolved), 
      family=binomial(link="logit"), data=dataFrame, 
      control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e4)))
assign('fit',fit,envir=parent.frame())
```

From that I get this output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation)
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: ts1_ev_access ~ ts1_age_grouped + ts1_sex + wheelchair_user +  
    stadt_land_code + ts1_language + (1 | MEDSTAT04_dissolved)
   Data: df
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 20000))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    1626     1689     -801     1602     1395 

Scaled residuals: 
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-2.659 -0.666  0.490  0.654  2.243 

Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 MEDSTAT04_dissolved (Intercept) 4.43e-17 6.66e-09
Number of obs: 1407, groups:  MEDSTAT04_dissolved, 162

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                  -1.4569     0.3055   -4.77 0.0000019 ***
ts1_age_grouped[30,45)        0.3846     0.2532    1.52   0.12879    
ts1_age_grouped[45,60)        0.2106     0.2414    0.87   0.38304    
ts1_age_grouped[60,76)        0.8019     0.2536    3.16   0.00157 ** 
ts1_age_grouped[76,120)       0.1706     0.3447    0.49   0.62069    
ts1_sexFemale                 0.2768     0.1370    2.02   0.04329 *  
wheelchair_user               2.0812     0.1347   15.45   < 2e-16 ***
stadt_land_codeIntermediate  -0.0661     0.2260   -0.29   0.76992    
stadt_land_codeUrban         -0.1588     0.2056   -0.77   0.43992    
ts1_languageFrench            0.5190     0.1496    3.47   0.00052 ***
ts1_languageItalian           0.4112     0.3006    1.37   0.17125    
---
Signif. codes:  0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1   1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) t1__[3 t1__[4 t1__[6 t1__[7 ts1_sF whlch_ std__I std__U ts1_lF
t1__[30,45) -0.625                                                               
t1__[45,60) -0.648  0.794                                                        
t1__[60,76) -0.662  0.761  0.794                                                 
t1__[76,120 -0.460  0.558  0.584  0.560                                          
ts1_sexFeml -0.125  0.008  0.009  0.020 -0.009                                   
wheelchr_sr -0.364  0.045  0.022  0.137  0.038  0.061                            
stdt_lnd_cI -0.511 -0.019 -0.017 -0.015  0.000 -0.037  0.005                     
stdt_lnd_cU -0.541 -0.037 -0.033 -0.029 -0.034 -0.052 -0.022  0.783              
ts1_lnggFrn -0.173  0.009 -0.003  0.019  0.008  0.036  0.187 -0.025 -0.006       
ts1_lnggItl -0.100  0.021  0.010  0.036  0.031  0.025  0.065  0.044 -0.008  0.122
convergence code: 0
singular fit
```

Now I use the effects package to show the effects:

```
effects <- allEffects(fit)
```

If I plot those results, I get this:

[image: plot from effects]

Questions:

1. Can I add p-values to those plot, to see if the results are significant?
2. How do I interpret those results? If I look at sex variable I would say something like that: Comparing male with female, if you're female the chance to experience hindrance due to access, is 6% higher, compared to male.